# Loading C# solution faster with Rosyln

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am developing a static analysis program for analyzing my project in C#.

I use Roslyn for this work. My project that I want to analyze is very big and about 300 projects. When I use below code, it takes about 1.5 min.

```
var solutionName="solutionPath.sln";
MSBuildWorkspace workSpace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution solution = workSpace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionName).Result;
```

1.5 minute loading time for me is more, because my Visual Studio loads this solution in about 10 seconds.

Is there any way to reduce this loading time?

Comment: Visual Studio keeps loading the projects in the background after opening the solution, so that's an unfair comparison. To speed it up, buy an SSD.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i use SSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not; that time is roughly what I'd expect for a solution of that size. Visual Studio is caching the result of the last time you loaded stuff (and no, there's no easy way to use that caching in MSBuildWorkspace). I bet if you deleted the hidden .vs folder by your solution and re-opened Visual Studio, it'd take about that long as well.

Comment: thanks for your response, I create a new Configuration and un-check the debug check-box for my projects in configuration Manager for my new configuration. and i load the solution in Roslyn with new configuration. I can load that faster than. but some limitation happened in this way. metadata for the projects was zero.